# Python - replace all words start with

Tags: python, replace

I would like to know how to delete all the words starts with "saison".

For exemple:

```
test = "This is an example of saison1, saison7 and saison58 could be deleted too"
#test = test.replace("saison1", "")
#test = test.replace("saison58", "")
```

To have:

```
test = "This is an example of ,  and  could be deleted too"
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

test = re.sub(r'\bsaison\d*\b', '', test)
```

This removes any occurrence of the text `saison` followed by 0 or more digits from `test`. The `\b` at the start and end ensures that you only match whole words, not words that happen to only *contain* `saison` (followed by digits) in the middle or end, or start with `saison` but end with something else.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "This is an example of saison1, saison7 and saison58 could be deleted too"
>>> re.sub(r'\bsaison\d*\b', '', test)
'This is an example of ,  and  could be deleted too'
```

Comment: Great, thank you. re is a module I don't control anymore, the syntax is a little complex. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
>>> ' '.join([ word for word in test.split() if not word.startswith('saison') ])
'This is an example of and could be deleted too'
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution delete the spaces too. However, please can you aprove my question, because I can't ask questions anymore.. Thanks in advance!