# How to replace a word as long as it satisfies a defined sub string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to substitute 'diag', 'diagnose' or 'diagnosis' or their typos (i.e. 'diagonoose', etc) to 'diagnose'. It seems all these words share the same pattern 'diag', just wonder how to make a substitute once it satisfies the condition: starts with (or contain) 'diag'.

I have tried the following, however, it doesn't seem to work

```
re.sub(r"\bdiag$\b","diagnose" , text)
```

Comment: Use `re.sub(r"\bdiag\w*", "diagnose", text)`

Comment: What's the definition of a typo? Do you consider "diagonal" a typo of diagnose?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This isn't a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440267/how-to-find-a-word-that-starts-with-a-specific-character because no answer on that page explains how to replace the word.

Comment: @Ruzihm It explains how to match a word starting with specific letter(s). OP here knows how to replace, hence, it is a valid dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a better candidate for duplicate marking would be this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064964/python-replace-all-words-start-with

Comment: @Ruzihm Added..

Comment: The current regexp will replace "diagnosis" with "diagnose", which is surely a bug. I think you should use a replacement function which looks up the word in a dict containing common typos.